# How do I delete a clash of clans village?

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I upgraded to a new phone and installed clash of clans and during setup I connected to Google plus thinking I could get my other village loaded but I hadn't connected to Google plus on my older village first. And when I tried connecting my older village to Google plus in order to get it to my new phone it has my brand new village loaded and won't let me override that village with the better one. How do I delete the new village in Google plus in order for my original village to be the primary?

Answer (score 1):

its very easy....
You just have to reinstall Clash of Clans on your device, and then tap login with G+. When it says, "Do you want to reload your previous village?" Hit cancel.
Done, you have started afresh!

Answer (score 1):

Linking in Clash of Clans is permanent. You cannot remove that link.
All you can do now is creating new Google account to make your village safe there. Then try to contact the support in game. They can help you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

- Disconnect from Google+ on the new phone
- Connect to Google+ on the old phone
- If it asks you if you want to load the new village, say no
- Connect to Google+ on the new phone
- It should ask you to load the old village

#### If that doesn't work:

- Uninstall Clash of Clans on the new phone
- Connect to Google+ on the old phone
- Install Clash of Clans on the new phone
- Connect to Google+ on the new phone