# Linked Account in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have both a tablet and cell phone with Clash of Clans installed.  When I originally began the game it was on my tablet (before you could link to Google).  Later I installed it on my phone, by then you could link to Google, which I did.  Then I went back to the tablet and tried to link to Google, but it keeps wanting to load my new village from my phone.  Even after unlinking from Google on my phone install it does the same thing.

How can I make the Google account forget about the version on my phone? So, I can then link the progressed village from my tablet, and re link the phone so I have both devices with the same version of my village (and I assume then update properly no matter what device I play on).

I would prefer not having to setup another Google account.

Comment: It looks like you overwrited your tablet's progress with your phone's progress.

Comment: I haven't destroyed the other version (yet), I keep cancelling the link when it wants to load the 'bad' version.

Comment: What tablet and phone do you have? It is possible that you can't connect Android to iOs. Maybe [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178210/how-do-i-delete-a-clash-of-clans-village?rq=1) helps

Comment: They are a GalaxyS5 and a Tab3, so both Android. Thanks for the link, that was the first stuff I tried, but it ended up being stored in the Google+ settings ... the step below in my own answer ended up getting it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/XTmiHxe-VsI

> Log into the google+ account, select the "Home" drop down in the upper
>   left hand corner. Select "settings", Scroll down to about half way
>   down and select "Manage apps and activities", Select the edit (pencil)
>   tool for clash of clans and select "disconnect". Make sure you check
>   the box that asks about erasing all activities for this App. It takes
>   about an hour for Google to erase all data for the app, but after that
>   you can then re-connect with the account you want to use.

and another one http://cocland.com/tutorials/removing-clash-of-clans-from-google-account

This was not an easy thing to track down via Google or even clicking through my Google+ account menus.  Hopefully this may help others.